# Match apostrophe with right single quote

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress

I am building auto linking feature in my wordpress plugin, with javascript and I have one problem.

On outputting post content wordpress converts apostrophes "'" in to right single quotation "’".

For example the post content in wordpress editor looks like this:

```
<div class"post-content">This is content and don't skip this.</div>
```

And on frontend apostrophe is replaced with html entity for "’":

```
This is content and don’t skip this.
```

Then I have javascript array which contain keywords which should be linked.
I have problem when my keyword contain apostrophe like:

```
 "don't skip"
```

I have this code:

```
var patern = new RegExp("\\bdon't skip\\b", "gi");

if (patern.test(node.data)) {
   link_keyword(node, element, link);
}
```

Where node.data is:

```
node.data = "This is content and don’t skip this."
```

And as you can see the keyword will not be find in node.data because in node data is instead apostrophe is right single quote.

I don't want to touch the content, so I tried to replace apostrophe in my keyword with right single quote "’" but then my keyword look like this:

```
don�t skip
```

If I replace apostrophe with html entity for right single quote "’" it will look like this:

```
don&rsquo;t skip
```

So in both cases ti will not match and it will not be replaced. 
So does anyone have idea how to handle chase when my keyword has apostrophe and in the post content is the same keyword which use right single quote instead apostrophe, how to find match.

Comment: Can you try: `var patern = new RegExp("\\bdon['’]t skip\\b", "gi");`

Comment: You have a problem with character encoding.

Comment: May be useful: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/please-give-us-the-option-to-turn-of-smart-quotes

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking for the right apostrophe, just check for a character like this

```
node.data = "This is content and don’t skip this.";    

var pattern = new RegExp("\\bdon\.*t skip\\b", "gi");

pattern.test(node.data);
=> true;
```

> This way you are not touching the data, and just in case there is no apostrophe, but just words it will still work. If you don't want it to work when there is no "'" then just remove the "*" after "\."